# membership testing for tuples containing np.arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to test for membership in a list/tuple that contains tuples of scalars, and np.arrays. It works fine with regular arrays, but not with np arrays.  The first print statement in the following prints "True", the second raises a `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

```
huge = [(5.0, [[ 3., -1.],
       [-1.,  2.]], [ 7.,  5.]), (2.0, [[ 2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.]]), [-2.,  5.], (2.0, [[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.]], [ 0.,  1.]), (1.0,[[ 0.2,  0.1],
       [ 0.1,  1. ]], [-3.,  4.])]
lil = (2.0,[[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.]],[ 0.,  1.])

nphuge = [(5.0, np.array([[ 3., -1.],
       [-1.,  2.]]), np.array([ 7.,  5.])), (2.0, np.array([[ 2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.]]), np.array([-2.,  5.])), (2.0, np.array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.]]), np.array([ 0.,  1.])), (1.0, np.array([[ 0.2,  0.1],
       [ 0.1,  1. ]]), np.array([-3.,  4.]))]
nplil = (2.0, np.array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.]]), np.array([ 0.,  1.]))


print lil in huge #Prints "True"

print nplil in nphuge #Raises ValueError
```

I can get around this by manually converting members of each tuple to regular lists rather than np.arrays:

```
nplil_work_around = nplil[0],nplil[1].tolist(),nplil[2].tolist()
nphuge_work_around = [(x[0],x[1].tolist(), x[2].tolist()) for x in nphuge]

print nplil_work_around in nphuge_work_around # prints True
```

Is there a way to do this without converting the np.arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
any( all((np.all(f==s) for f, s in zip(nplil, nphuge[i]))) for i in range(len(nphuge)) )
```

Step by step:

```
>>> nphuge = [(5.0, np.array([[ 3., -1.],
       [-1.,  2.]]), np.array([ 7.,  5.])), (2.0, np.array([[ 2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.]]), np.array([-2.,  5.])), (2.0, np.array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.]]), np.array([ 0.,  1.])), (1.0, np.array([[ 0.2,  0.1],
       [ 0.1,  1. ]]), np.array([-3.,  4.]))]
>>> nplil = (2.0, np.array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.]]), np.array([ 0.,  1.]))

In [54]: [np.all(f==s) for f, s in zip(nplil, nphuge[0])]
Out[54]: [False, False, False]

In [55]: [np.all(f==s) for f, s in zip(nplil, nphuge[1])]
Out[55]: [True, False, False]

In [56]: [np.all(f==s) for f, s in zip(nplil, nphuge[2])]
Out[56]: [True, True, True]

>>> [ all((np.all(f==s) for f, s in zip(nplil, nphuge[i]))) for i in range(len(nphuge)) ]
[False, False, True, False]
>>> any( [ all((np.all(f==s) for f, s in zip(nplil, nphuge[i]))) for i in range(len(nphuge)) ] )
True
```